# New Web Inspector for Safari?

Tags: safari, development

If you visit [this page](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/whats-new.html), it seems there's a new version of Web Inspector for Safari. ([screenshot](http://grab.by/opNy))

How can I access that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be describing Safari as it *will* exist in the upcoming release of OS X Mavericks. So there are two straightforward ways to get the new Web Inspector:

1. Become a member of the [Mac Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/) and install the Mavericks Developer Preview
2. Wait until Mavericks is released to the public and upgrade to it